# How can I turn this TediousJS response into a stream?

Tags: node.js, http, tedious

I currently have this code that builds up a 2mb json object. Upon completion it uses res.json(response) and sends the cached data to my client. I envision that this will cause scalability problems if it is not handled in chunks.

What do I do to achieve this?

```
var response = {};
connection.on('connect', function(err){
    var request = new Request(query, function(err, fowCount, rows){
        if(err){res.json(err);}
        else{
            for(var r=0; r<rows.length; r++){
                for(var c=1; c<drugs.length+1; c++){
                    if(response[rows[0][c].metadata.colName.toLowerCase()] === undefined){
                        response[rows[0][c].metadata.colName.toLowerCase()] = {};
                    }
                    response[rows[0][c].metadata.colName.toLowerCase()][rows[r][0].value] = rows[r][c].value;
                }
            }
            res.json(response); //2mb response is a bit large for my taste
        }
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
});
```

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the scalability concern isn't that you're assigning a 2MB object to the response, but that you're building up a 2MB object in the first place. You'd presumably want to stream the response directly out of the DB or off disk so that only a tiny fraction of that 2MB is in memory ad any given moment. But if you must run some kind of transform on the data structure as a whole, maybe there is simply no way around this.

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of any other way other than just streaming rows to the client and performing the data transform there.

Comment: Another approach that may or may not work in your case is to store the data in the form you want to retrieve it, which goes against common SQL practice, but is sometimes how things are done in the NO-SQL world.